# async custom hooks does't provide updated data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple hook to help me handle a POST request. With the following code, I expect `unsub` will be `true` after the POST is done. Can anyone point out anything I could have done wrong?

**Custom Hook**

```js
const useUnsubscribeEmail = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [unsub, setUnSub] = useState();
  const UNSUB_URL = '/web-registry-api/v1/reviews/unsubscription';
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
      // async POST call
      (async () => {
        try {
          await ApiService.post(`${UNSUB_URL}/${userId}`);
          // update unsub value
          setUnSub(true);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [userId]);

  return [unsub, setUserId];
};

export default useUnsubscribeEmail;
```

**Component**

```js
const ReviewUnsubscription = () => {
  const { userId } = useParams();
  const [unsub, unsubscribeEmail] = useUnsubscribeEmail();
  return (
    <MinimumLayout>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h1>Unsubscribe from email reminders to review products you’ve received from Zola?{unsub}</h1>
        {/* unsub here is still undefined */}
        <Button disabled={unsub} onClick={() => { unsubscribeEmail(userId); }} variant="primary" className={styles.button}>Unsubscribe</Button>
      </div>
    </MinimumLayout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the `ApiService` call not throwing? Did you verify the state is correctly set within the hook?

Comment: @Qwerty I retry my implementation again, It works now.  Thanks for checking my code. It is a good reminder that I should always state within the hook

Answer (score 0):

unsub is still going to be undefined until you click the button as you have not set a default state for it in your hook.
change :  `const [unsub, setUnSub] = useState();` to  `const [unsub, setUnSub] = useState(false);` is what I would recommend

I tested on my side and works just fine; However, I cannot test the APIService.post.

Comment: Thanks for testing my code. It actually does work. Sorry for making it clean in the OP, `unsub` was designed to changed on click events. Also, I don't think unsub needs a default state in this case since `undefined` is falsy. ANyway, thanks for checking my code .